# How to instantaneously update changes committed to vuex store in the ui of another component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

How to instantaneously update changes committed to vuex store in the ui of another component?

following is the vuex store module of a component

```
const { property } = require("lodash")
export default {
  state: {
    data: [
        {id: 1, name: 'Angular', status: 'active'},
        {id: 2, name: 'React', status: 'active'},
        {id: 3, name: 'Vue', status: 'inactive'},
    ]
  },
  mutations: {
    UPDATE_ITEM(state, payload) {
        const item = state.data.find(item => _.isEqual(item, payload.item))

      Object.assign(item, payload.status);
    },
  },
  actions: {
    updateItem({ commit }, payload) {
      commit("UPDATE_ITEM", payload);
    },
  },
  getters: {
getData: (state) => state.data,
getMappedStatus: (state) => state.data.map(data => data.status)
  },
};
```

this is how I get mapped status in component 1

```
computed: {
    getMappedStatus() {
      return  this.$store.geters.getMappedStatus
    }
}
```

and inside the ui of component 1

```
<ul>
<li v-for="item in getMappedStatus>{{item}} </li>
</ul>
```

from another component 2 I'm updating the changes as the user inputs the status:

```
onStatusChanges(item, status) {
    this.$store.dispatch("updateItem", {
        item, status
    });
  },
```

But the problem is that even though the state is getting updated the ui is not getting updated.But
(inside component 1)

I think it is because of the computed property. ... not sure.

How can I implement something like and observable or something reactive so that the getMappedStatus computed property in component 1 will get updated automatically as action is dispatched from component 2.

**NOTE** Both components come under the same vuex store module

If this was in angular/ngrx I would subscribe to the selectors inside the component 1 and I would get instantaneously the changes. even If I subscribe to the event inside the onInit() method or constructor() and do a console.log() the changes from the other component will be reflected instantaneously.

But this is not happening with vuex.

How can I achieve that:?

or is there a way to trigger the updation of the getMappedStatus computed property inside component 1 as soon as changes occurs from component 2:

```
computed: {
    getMappedStatus() {
      return  this.$store.geters.getMappedStatus
    }
}
```

so that the ui of component 1 updates instantaneously.

Comment: `updateItem` action returns a `<promise>`. Commit a mutation to vuex store in `then` block. and then use computed in what ever component you want.

Comment: Yeah. But updateItem is an action dispatched from another component. But I need the changes to be reflected in a different component via the getters.

Answer (score 0):

You need to **return something** from `getMappedStatus`

```js
computed: {
    getMappedStatus() {
        return this.$store.geters.getMappedStatus
    }
}
```

...without a `return` statement the `this.$store.geters.getMappedStatus` is just an expression and your computed property always returns `undefined` (because JS functions without `return` always return `undefined`)

Comment: I missed that to type in ... In the real app it is getting returned... it's just a mistake on stack overflow.... inside my app component it is returned... sorry.. But that's not the issue..!

Answer (score 0):

We can think of `getters` as computed properties for stores. Like computed properties, a getter's result is cached based on its dependencies, and will only re-evaluate when some of its dependencies have changed so that simply means if `component1` mutates the state in `vuex` store and `component2` uses that property from the store it will automatically update in all components using it.

Online IDE - [Live Demo Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vuejs-vuex-starter-bjsm4g?file=button-counter.component.js)

**Vuex Store**

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
   state: {
     name: 'mex'
   },
   mutations: {
     mutateName(state, value) {
       state.name = value;
     }
   },
   actions: {
     updateName(context, payload) {
       context.commit('mutateName', payload.name);
     }
   },
   getters: {
     getName(state) {
       return state.name;
     }
   }
});
```

The `changeName` method when fired will dispatch `updateName` action which will update the name and all the components will update accordingly because it's reactive.

**Then In Any Component**

```
computed:{
  name() {
    return this.$store.getters.getName
  }
},
methods: {
  changeName: function () {
    this.$store.dispatch('updateName', {  name: 'mexxxxx'});
  }
}
```

Comment: I missed that to type in ... In the real app it is getting returned... it's just a mistake on stack overflow.... inside my app component it is returned... sorry.. But that's not the issue..!